# ORA-12582: TNS:invalid operation, using CLOB datatype in database table

Tags: .net, oracle11g

We are having 2 servers. I am working with .Net and oracle. Both the servers are having same oracle version 11g (11.2.0.1.0).

One scenario (getting values from Database table, in that one column datatype is CLOB and binding to div) is working fine in one server. But the same scenario is
giving exception in another server.

The .net application log says,

```
2015-05-22 10:26:16,836 [152152] ERROR System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-12582: TNS:invalid operation
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleLob.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
  at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleLob.get_Value()
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleColumn.GetValue(NativeBuffer_RowBuffer buffer)
  at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
  at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
  at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
```

I have searched regarding this issue, and i found only this,

```
Action: Not normally visible to the user. For further details, turn on tracing and reexecute the operation. If error persists, contact Oracle Customer Support.
```

I dint find any other solution. Also, i dont know what to do regarding this issue.

Note : All other database related things are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked for me. Instead of taking the CLOB data directly, i have done like this...

```
DBMS_LOB.substr(VALUE, 5000) AS VALUE
```

Not sure, whether this the right solution. But it worked for me.

Comment: You should accept this answer, this worked for me too. I was getting this because I was trying to format a CLOB without converting it to VARCHAR first.